# Timeout R package installation from Github

Tags: r, curl, github, timeout

I'm trying to install a package from github for R with `devtools` package.
But I'm encountering Timeout error from curl each time!

> install_github('ramhiser/datamicroarray')

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached
```

Any Idea why this happens? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you use proxy ?

Comment: @Batanichek No! I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I want to download this package it also takes long to get a  connection but in the end it works as expected. Another possibility is to download the [zip file](https://github.com/ramhiser/datamicroarray/archive/master.zip) and then install it.

To install the package after downloading, the following code works:

```
install.packages("/address/to/zip-package", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

and write the address of the downloaded package in place of `/address/to/zip-package`, or use RStudio and Packages -> Install.