# Installing the caret package in R

Tags: r, r-caret

How long does it generally take to install caret package in R? I ran install.packages('caret', dependencies = TRUE), and R has been running the install for close to an hour now. Is this normal?

Comment: No. It does have a lot of dependencies, so maybe if you're using your old 28.8 modem it could take a while...

Comment: An advice: sometimes it's better to download the package and install it ofline. [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410148/timeout-r-package-installation-from-github).

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't take that long, I actually had to install the Caret package on one of my machines earlier today and it took less than a minute. Sounds like you might want to check your connection speed.

Answer (score 0):

With dependencies, it can take a while, mine took about 30mins and my download speed was around 18Mbps max, it had 648 dependencies as of Nov19.  With-out dependencies, it is fast, as the answer from the_SJC suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = c("Depends", "Suggests"))
```

the install took about 5 hours for me with 100Mbps internet.

---

Adding to that, it still didn't install what I needed. This worked:

```
install.packages("caret", dependencies = TRUE)
```

it took about 10 minutes.