# Sentiment Analysis using R: github 'okugami79/sentiment140' package installation error

Tags: r, github, sentiment-analysis, devtools

I wish to install sentiment140 github package by developer okugami79. I wrote following script for the same:

```
install.packages("githubinstall")
require(devtools)
library(githubinstall)
install_github('sentiment140', 'okugami79')
library(sentiment)
```

But it threw an error:

> Installation failed: Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Timed out
>   Warning message: Username parameter is deprecated. Please use okugami79/sentiment140

Then I modified installation statement as follows:

```
install_github('okugami79/sentiment140')
```

Still it threw an error:

> Installation failed: Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Timed out

I checked for solution on stackoverflow through following link:

[Timeout R package installation from Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410148/timeout-r-package-installation-from-github)

Here, I found a way to install github package by downloading package zip file and installing it in R using:

```
install.packages("/address/to/zip-package", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

This also prompts error:

> Warning: invalid package 'sentiment-master'
>   Error: ERROR: no packages specified
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\u257449\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "sentiment-master"' had status 1
>   Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘sentiment-master’ had non-zero exit status

How should I go about installing required package from github in R ? Your valuable advice/solution is requested.

Thank You !

Answer (score 0):

Just a straightforward pair of functions installed this package from Github source for me on both Windows and OSX.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github('okugami79/sentiment140')
```

There may be something unusual about your system setup, in which case, it would be helpful to have your session information. You can get that by entering `sessionInfo()`.

**However**, note that this package you are looking to install is over 4 years old per the [description file](https://github.com/okugami79/sentiment140/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) on Github. A lot of work has gone into other packages that work with natural language processing and sentiment analysis. The [CRAN Task View for Natural Language Processing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html) is a good place to start for an overview of many of these packages that can be installed directly from CRAN. There are many resources that are better maintained. For example, here's a [chapter](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html) on sentiment analysis using the `tidytext` package.

Comment: Thank You for your advice @dshkol. I will surely use all options suggested by you.